# Read content of the folder path

Tags: python, windows

Can anyone explain how to work with paths with python on windows.

the path is given as parameter

```
path = 'C:\Data\Projects\IHateWindows\DEV_Main\Product\ACSF\Dev\DEV\force.com\src\aura'
```

Im trying to get the content of the folder but is not a valid path
is reading the path as:

```
'C:\\Data\\Projects\\IHateWindows\\DEV_Main\\Product\\ACSF\\Dev\\DEV\x0corce.com\\src\x07ura'
```

trying some solutions...

```
for f in listdir(path.replace("\\", "\\\\")): print (f)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\\\Data\\\\Projects\\\\Prd_Development\\\\DEV_Main\\\\Product\\\\ACSF\\\\Dev\\\\DEV\x0corce.com\\\\src\x07ura'


for f in listdir(path.replace("\\", "/")): print (f)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/Data/Projects/Prd_Development/DEV_Main/Product/ACSF/Dev/DEV\x0corce.com/src\x07ura'
```

**EDIT:
Solution**

```
path = path.replace("\a", "\\a").replace("\f", "\\f")
```

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Try use \\ or / when assign value to `path`.

Comment: Note: your edit shows you are trying to modify the path *inside Python*. That is where you go wrong. You must **enter it correctly** -- with double backslashes or single forward slashes. Trying to use `replace` inside Python is 'too late'. (So it **is** a duplicate after all, and the answer(s) there should help you further.)

Comment: As I said tthe path s received as parameter, It comes how it comes....

Comment: @usr2564301 You can modify the path in Pytohn. The only thing is that you need to know what you have at the beginning clearly, and not to get messed up with the str representation.

Comment: @Mathieu: no, as soon as the path is entered **with the wrong string representation** -- single backslashes instead of doubles -- *you cannot know what the original string was*. You can't blindly replace every `\f` with `\\f`, for example.

Comment: @usr2564301 Agree.

Answer (score -1):

A single Backslash is a escape character in Python. Therefore you might need to use double Backslashes or a forward slash:

```
path = 'C:\\Data\\Projects\\IHateWindows\\DEV_Main\\Product\\ACSF\\Dev\\DEV\\force.com\\src\\aura'
```

or

```
path = 'C:/Data/Projects/IHateWindows/DEV_Main/Product/ACSF/Dev/DEV/force.com/src/aura'
```